conditionQualifiedByName is not getting applied with mapstruct

public class BaseMapper {

    @Condition
    @Named("isStringNotNullOrEmpty")

    public boolean isStringNotNullOrEmpty(String input) {

        return StringUtils.isNotEmpty(input);

    }

}

@Mapper

public abstract class EmployeeMapper extends BaseMapper {

    @Mappings({

        @Mapping(source="gender", target="gender", conditionQualifiedByName="isStringNotNullOrEmpty", qualifiedByName="toGender")})

        public abstract Target transformSource(Source employee);

}

@Generated(

    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",

    date = "2024-08-12T21:14:39+0530",

    comments = "version: 1.5.5.Final, compiler: javac, environment: Java 11.0.23 (Homebrew)"

)

public class Target extends EmployeeMapper {

 

    @Override

    public Target transformSource(Source employee) {

        if ( employee == null ) {

            return null;

        }

 

        Target.Builder target = Target.newBuilder();

        target.gender( toGender( employee.getGender() ) );

 

        return target.build();

    }

}

I want to keep a null and empty check on string to avoid mapping source gender to target gender
How to fix this ? Please help
I am expecting to be able generate Implementation class code with isStringNotNullOrEmpty if check before toGender() but only toGender is getting applied for mapping employee gender.
please let me know if there is an alternative way to do this.

BaseMapper should be annotated with @Mapper and not @Setter?

@Luca Basso Ricci
i removed annotation Setter and added annotation Mapper but still conditionQualifiedByName not got applied in the implementation class

I’m voting to close this question because it looks like it was asked twice already. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78866278/mapstruct-conditionqualifiedbyname-not-getting-applied-in-the-implementation-cla
