MapStruct conditionQualifiedByName not getting applied in the Implementation class of mapper
conditionQualifiedByName is not getting applied here with mapstruct.
@Setter
public class BaseUpdateEmployeeMapper extends BaseDesktopMapper<Source, Target> {
    @Named("isStringNotNullOrEmpty")
    public boolean isStringNotNullOrEmpty(String input) {
        return StringUtils.isNotEmpty(input);
    }
}

@Mapper
public abstract class EmployeeMapper extends BaseMapper {
    @Mappings({
        @Mapping(source="gender", target="gender", conditionQualifiedByName="isStringNotNullOrEmpty", qualifiedByName="toGender"),
        public abstract Target transformSource(Source employee);
}

@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2024-08-12T21:14:39+0530",
    comments = "version: 1.5.5.Final, compiler: javac, environment: Java 11.0.23 (Homebrew)"
)
public class Target extends EmployeeMapper {

    @Override
    public Target transformSource(Source employee) {
        if ( employee == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Target.Builder target = Target.newBuilder();
        target.gender( toGender( employee.getGender() ) );

        return target.build();
    }
}

I want to keep a null and empty check on string to avoid mapping source gender to target gender
How to fix this ? Please help
I am expecting to be able generate Impl code with isStringNotNullOrEmpty if check before toGender() but only toGender is getting applied for mapping employee gender.

The reason why the condition is not getting applied is due to the fact that the condition method (isStringNotNullOrEmpty) should be annotated with @Condition for it to be considered as a presence check method
